# Accessing struct array using double pointers in c

Tags: c

```
typedef enum
{
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2,
    THREE = 3
}Count_t;

typedef enum
{
    RED = 0,
    BLUE = 1,
    GREEN = 2
}Color_t;

typedef struct
{
    Count_t Count_en;
    Color_t Color_en;
}Grp_t;

Grp_t const Grp_ena[]=
{
        { ONE,    RED },
        { TWO,    BLUE },
        { THREE,  GREEN}
};

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int   num;
    Grp_t        * Grp_stp;
}Try_t;

Try_t const Try_sta[] =
{
        { 7,      &Grp_ena[0] },
        { 8,      &Grp_ena[1] },
        { 9,      &Grp_ena[2] },
};

int main()
{
       Try_t   **p = Try_sta;
}
```

Using double pointer `**p` , I want to access the elements of LUT `Try_sta`. With single dimensional pointer I am able to access the struct array elements. But with 2d pointer I failed to access. Is there any proper way to do it?

Comment: How do you imagine to access the elements? How would the pointer arithmetic know what the underlying type is?

Comment: `p[0]->num` and `p[0]->Grp_stp->Count_en`. But this is not working.

Comment: Did you try p = &Try_sta

Comment: You probably want `Try_t   (*p)[3] = Try_sta;`

Comment: @PtitXav - Yes.

Comment: @JHBonarius I have tried this also  `Try_t   (*p)[3] = Try_sta;`, But I am not able to access.

Comment: Not sure you can do it because p[i] must be a pointer to Try_sta[i]. So you must have an array of 3 pointers (one each element of Try_sta)